# Google Calendar Event Not Showing in Calendar

Tags: c#, google-api, google-calendar-api, google-api-dotnet-client, service-accounts

We have created a Service Account in Google and Using Calendar API for adding events, it worked fine before ,after google stopped the account and reactivated it , it didn't work

We have tried new service account and debugged line by line of our code and no error and also returning created events but not showing in calendar

```
        CalendarService service = null;
        var serviceAccountCredentialFilePath = 
        Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, 
        "ServiceAccount_Key.json");
        if (Path.GetExtension(serviceAccountCredentialFilePath).ToLower() 
        == ".json")
        {
            GoogleCredential credential;

            string[] scopes = new string[] {
                CalendarService.Scope.Calendar, // Manage your calendars
                CalendarService.Scope.CalendarReadonly // View your Calendars
             };
            using (var stream = new FileStream(serviceAccountCredentialFilePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
            {
                credential = GoogleCredential.FromStream(stream)
                     .CreateScoped(scopes);
            }
            // Create the service.
            service = new CalendarService(new BaseClientService.Initializer
            {
                HttpClientInitializer = credential,
                ApplicationName = "Esoco"
            });
        }
        // End //

        // Insert Event //
        var myEvent = new Event
        {
            Id = guid,
            //Transparency =  "OPAQUE",
            Summary = subject,
            Location = location,
            Start = new EventDateTime { TimeZone = timezone, DateTime = start },
            End = new EventDateTime { TimeZone = timezone, DateTime = end },
            Attendees = objattendees,
            Organizer = organizerdata,
            Description = summary,

        };

        myEvent.Start.DateTimeRaw = myEvent.Start.DateTimeRaw.Replace("Z", "");
        myEvent.End.DateTimeRaw = myEvent.End.DateTimeRaw.Replace("Z", "");

        //myEvent.ICalUID

        var recurringEvent = service.Events.Insert(myEvent, "primary");
        recurringEvent.SendNotifications = true;
        try
        {
            var outputofevent = recurringEvent.Execute();
            ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, typeof(string), "Alertscript", "alert('"+outputofevent.Status+"')", true);
        }
```

Expected Result is Inserted Event Display in Calendar but Actual Result is Not Displayed in Calendar

Comment: How do you know its not showing in the calendar?  are you doing an event.list to check?

Comment: Please check Trash (under settings). May be events are cancelled automatically. I am facing same issue.

Comment: @DaImTo yes its returned as 250

Comment: Then the event is being inserted.  Have you scanned though the events returned by events.list to find the one you are after and done an event.get to see what attendees have been sent?

Comment: @DaImTo - Yes all the events have my name in attendees and i also executed an event get method by event id and it returned the details

Comment: Then again whats the problem?

Comment: Google Calendar not displaying the events

Answer (score 5):

In the past few weeks, my team have the same issues,
and this is what my team's workaround.

Our scenario

1. We create a service account called `google-calendar@mycompany.iam.gserviceaccount.com`
2. We using service account's credential from 1) for Google Calendar API
3. Create an event into a service account's calendar like the code below

```
calendar.events.insert({
  calendarId: 'primary', // it will create an event into service account's calendar
  resource: data,
  sendNotifications: true
})
```

---

What we have done for a workaround.

1. Create a new company's user (let's say `system@mycompany.com`)
2. Share `system@mycompany.com`'s calendar with a service account by

   - going to "Calendar > Settings > Share with specific people" then
   - adding `google-calendar@mycompany.iam.gserviceaccount.com` with "Make changes to events"
3. Update the code from creating an event to service account's calendar to just-created-user's calendar like a below

```
calendar.events.insert({
  calendarId: 'system@mycompany.com', // << we changed from 'primary' to just-created-user
  resource: data,
  sendNotifications: true
})
```

After changing it, the created-event will be shown in Google Calendar as what it should.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 2):

remember that the following code inserts your events into the service accounts primary calendar

```
var recurringEvent = service.Events.Insert(myEvent, "primary");
```

In order to see these events you will need to either do an events.list or invite someone else to the event so that they can see it in their own calendar.

## Bug issue logged.

Beyond that there is currently an issue on the forums about invites not being sent https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/140746812

Comment: Yes i executed the events.list and its getting as 250 and also this is the html link of created event: https://www.google.com/calendar/event?eid=NGVocWdsaG5kaHRzNjh1ZjNmN2w0bTkxYmMgd2FiY29lc29jb0B3YWJjby1lc29jby5pYW0uZ3NlcnZpY2VhY2NvdW50LmNvbQ . when i opened this link im getting Could+not+find+the+requested+event  in the url...response url: https://calendar.google.com/calendar/r?msg=Could+not+find+the+requested+event.&msgtok=8c0c9622719986994bcfe33cae9e1a5e7e1430ae&t=AKUaPmbkGBRmYSzV9MjFtHHRH5uVFWdLmiUBpasM54XwMvOWv-Lxruj2Uo8ZNT5EpWx16c-Ln-gEUEgcpjgLoDALZKgDbzELNQ%3D%3D&sf=true

Comment: Invited my colleagues email id in the attendees.. and they didn't get invited.

Comment: Check the Google calendar questions over the last few days everyone having issues with not getting invite notifications.  https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/140746812

Comment: @dalmTo - the calendar is not getting blocked for the attendees.

Comment: Then what exactly is the issue?

Comment: Issue is calendar blocking is not happening when we execute the event insert api using service account.

Comment: How do you know its not happening?  Have you done a events.list to see if the event is there?