# Google Calendar Java API stopped sending invitation to attendees

Tags: google-api, google-calendar-api, google-api-java-client, service-accounts, google-iam

I have a gserviceaccount for my application that sends invitations to some Google Calendar events, so I use Java API for that (class `com.google.api.services.calendar.Calendar`, to be precise). It worked like a charm for more than year, but now I'm having some troubles with that as it just stopped working. I still can create new events via API and invite participants, later I can see they are saved properly (when getting this event from API, I can see the participants' emails), but the participants do not receive any emails or other kinds of invitation (they are not aware of the event at all)

I have already tried to delete and invite atteendees and events programatically, but nothing happened. When I create an event using normal Calendar app and then invite to this event (using app, not API), I get the invitation properly.

```
import com.google.api.services.calendar.model.Event;
import com.google.api.services.calendar.model.EventAttendee;


Event event = service.events().get(CALENDAR_ID, columnDay.getGoogleCalendarEvent().getGoogleEventId()).execute();
        event.getAttendees().add(new EventAttendee().setEmail("foo@example.com"));
        service.events().update(CALENDAR_ID, event.getId(), event).setSendNotifications(Boolean.TRUE).execute();
```

I expect the attendee to be saved and an email to be sent, but only a attendee is saved and I can't see any sort of invitation (email or anything). I don't get any errors.

Comment: issue has already been logged https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/140746812

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google Calendar Event Not Showing in Calendar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57870310/google-calendar-event-not-showing-in-calendar)